# Error: The security validation for this page is invalid

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, error, rest

I have as simple function to just upload 1 document in 1 library. I made a REST service as part of a SharePoint solution which I deploy/debug against sp2013.

However the `list.Rootfolder.Files.Add` gives me a "the security validation for this page is invalid"

```
    static public void UploadFileInLib(string subfolderPath, string fileName, byte[] doc)
    {
        //Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();

        SPSite site1 = SPContext.Current.Site;

        SPUserToken sysToken = SPContext.Current.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken;
        if (sysToken == null)
        {
           SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
           {
               using (SPSite site2 = new SPSite(site1.ServerRelativeUrl))
                {
                    sysToken = site2.SystemAccount.UserToken;
                }
           });
        }

        using (SPSite site2 = new SPSite(site1.Url, sysToken))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site2.OpenWeb(site1.Url))
            {
                string uploadPathRoot = site2.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Lists/abc";
                SPList list = web.GetList(uploadPathRoot);
                var fcp = new Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollectionAddParameters();
                fcp.Overwrite = true;
                list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileName, doc, fcp);
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I added the `X-RequestDigest` header to the JavasScript Proxy to the REST Service it all fell into place.

Add `{"X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()}` to the headers send.

Comment: how do we do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `web.Allowunsafeupdates = true;`

```
string uploadPathRoot = site2.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Lists/abc";
SPList list = web.GetList(uploadPathRoot);
var fcp = new Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollectionAddParameters();
fcp.Overwrite = true;
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileName, doc, fcp);
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Comment: I tried that before but did not work

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach is to perform

```
SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();
```

in order to check the validity of the request.